# D3 v4 Realtime Chart with Brushing

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to get [this block](https://bl.ocks.org/boeric/3b57a788a4b96e1af211) working with d3 v4 and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've placed my code in a fiddle, there is an issue with the setInterval and brushing - the extent is expecting a date object but I'm not sure how to get it.

```
function realTimeChart() {

  var version = "0.1.0",
      datum, initialData, data,
      maxSeconds = 300, pixelsPerSecond = 10,
      svgWidth = 700, svgHeight = 300,
      margin = { top: 20, bottom: 20, left: 50, right: 30, topNav: 10, bottomNav: 20 },
      dimension = { chartTitle: 20, xAxis: 20, yAxis: 20, xTitle: 20, yTitle: 20, navChart: 70 },
      barWidth = 3,
      maxY = 100, minY = 0,
      chartTitle, yTitle, xTitle,
      drawXAxis = true, drawYAxis = true, drawNavChart = true,
      border,
      selection,
      barId = 0;

  // create the chart
  var chart = function(s) {
    selection = s;
    if (selection == undefined) {
      console.error("selection is undefined");
      return;
    };

    // process titles
    chartTitle = chartTitle || "";
    xTitle = xTitle || "";
    yTitle = yTitle || "";

    // compute component dimensions
    var chartTitleDim = chartTitle == "" ? 0 : dimension.chartTitle;
    var xTitleDim = xTitle == "" ? 0 : dimension.xTitle;
    var yTitleDim = yTitle == "" ? 0 : dimension.yTitle;
    var xAxisDim = !drawXAxis ? 0 : dimension.xAxis;
    var yAxisDim = !drawYAxis ? 0 : dimension.yAxis;
    var navChartDim = !drawNavChart ? 0 : dimension.navChart;

    // compute chart dimension and offset
    var marginTop = margin.top + chartTitleDim;
    var height = svgHeight - marginTop - margin.bottom - chartTitleDim - xTitleDim - xAxisDim - navChartDim + 30;
    var heightNav = navChartDim - margin.topNav - margin.bottomNav;
    var marginTopNav = svgHeight - margin.bottom - heightNav - margin.topNav;
    var width = svgWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
    var widthNav = width;

    // append the svg
    var svg = selection.append("svg")
        .attr("width", svgWidth)
        .attr("height", svgHeight)
        .style("border", function(d) { 
          if (border) return "1px solid lightgray"; 
          else return null;
        });

    // create main group and translate
    var main = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate (" + margin.left + "," + marginTop + ")");

    // define clip-path
    main.append("defs").append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", "myClip")
      .append("rect")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    // create chart background
    main.append("rect")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .style("fill", "#f5f5f5");

    // note that two groups are created here, the latter assigned to barG;
    // the former will contain a clip path to constrain objects to the chart area; 
    // no equivalent clip path is created for the nav chart as the data itself
    // is clipped to the full time domain
    var barG = main.append("g")
        .attr("class", "barGroup")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0, 0)")
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#myClip")
      .append("g");

    // add group for x axis
    var xAxisG = main.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");

    // add group for y axis
    var yAxisG = main.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis");

    // in x axis group, add x axis title
    xAxisG.append("text")
        .attr("class", "title")
        .attr("x", width / 2)
        .attr("y", 25)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .text(function(d) { 
          var text = xTitle == undefined ? "" : xTitle;
          return text; 
        });

    // in y axis group, add y axis title
    yAxisG.append("text")
        .attr("class", "title")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("x", - height / 2)
        .attr("y", -35)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .text(function(d) { 
          var text = yTitle == undefined ? "" : yTitle;
          return text; 
        });

    // in main group, add chart title
    main.append("text")
        .attr("class", "chartTitle")
        .attr("x", width / 2)
        .attr("y", -20)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .text(function(d) { 
          var text = chartTitle == undefined ? "" : chartTitle;
          return text; 
        });

    // define main chart scales
    var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([minY, maxY]).range([height, 0]);

    // define main chart axis
    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);
    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

    // add nav chart
    var nav = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate (" + margin.left + "," + marginTopNav + ")");

    // add nav background
    nav.append("rect")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", heightNav)
        .style("fill", "#F5F5F5")
        .style("shape-rendering", "crispEdges")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0, 0)");

    // add group to hold line and area paths
    var navG = nav.append("g")
        .attr("class", "nav");

    // add group to hold nav x axis
    var xAxisGNav = nav.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + heightNav + ")");

    // define nav scales
    var xNav = d3.scaleTime().range([0, widthNav]);
    var yNav = d3.scaleLinear().domain([minY, maxY]).range([heightNav, 0]);

    // define nav axis
    var xAxisNav = d3.axisBottom(xNav);

    // define function that will draw the nav area chart
    var navArea = d3.area()
        .x(function (d) { return xNav(d.time); })
        .y1(function (d) { return yNav(d.value); })
        .y0(heightNav);

    // define function that will draw the nav line chart
    var navLine = d3.line()
        .x(function (d) { return xNav(d.time); })
        .y(function (d) { return yNav(d.value); });

    // compute initial time domains...
    var ts = new Date().getTime();

    // first, the full time domain
    var endTime = new Date(ts);
    var startTime = new Date(endTime.getTime() - maxSeconds * 1000);
    var interval = endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime();

    // then the viewport time domain (what's visible in the main chart 
    // and the viewport in the nav chart)
    var endTimeViewport = new Date(ts);
    var startTimeViewport = new Date(endTime.getTime() - width / pixelsPerSecond * 1000);
    var intervalViewport = endTimeViewport.getTime() - startTimeViewport.getTime();
    var offsetViewport = startTimeViewport.getTime() - startTime.getTime();

    // set the scale domains for main and nav charts
    x.domain([startTimeViewport, endTimeViewport]);
    xNav.domain([startTime, endTime]); 

    // update axis with modified scale
    xAxis.scale(x)(xAxisG);
    yAxis.scale(y)(yAxisG);
    xAxisNav.scale(xNav)(xAxisGNav);

    // create brush (moveable, changable rectangle that determines 
    // the time domain of main chart)
    var sel;
    var viewport = d3.brush()
        // .x(xNav)
        .extent([startTimeViewport, endTimeViewport])
        .on("brush", function () {
          // get the current time extent of viewport
          // var extent = viewport.extent();
          var extent = d3.event.selection || x.range();

          console.log(extent);
          startTimeViewport = extent[0];
          endTimeViewport = extent[1];
          intervalViewport = endTimeViewport.getTime() - startTimeViewport.getTime();
          offsetViewport = startTimeViewport.getTime() - startTime.getTime();

          // handle invisible viewport
          if (intervalViewport == 0) {
            intervalViewport = maxSeconds * 1000;
            offsetViewport = 0;
          }

          // update the x domain of the main chart
          x.domain((extent === null) ? xNav.domain() : extent);

          // update the x axis of the main chart
          xAxis.scale(x)(xAxisG);

          // update display
          refresh();
        });

      window.viewport = viewport;

    // create group and assign to brush
    var viewportG = nav.append("g")
        .attr("class", "viewport")
        .call(viewport)
        .selectAll("rect")
        .attr("height", heightNav);


    // initial invocation
    data = initialData || [];

    // update display
    refresh();


    // function to refresh the viz upon changes of the time domain 
    // (which happens constantly), or after arrival of new data,
    // or at init
    function refresh() {

      // process data to remove too late or too early data items 
      // (the latter could occur if the chart is stopped, while data
      // is being pumped in)
      data = data.filter(function(d) {
        if (d.time.getTime() > startTime.getTime() &&
            d.time.getTime() < endTime.getTime()) 
          return true;
      })

      // here we bind the new data to the main chart
      // note: no key function is used here; therefore the data binding is
      // by index, which effectivly means that available DOM elements
      // are associated with each item in the available data array, from 
      // first to last index; if the new data array contains fewer elements
      // than the existing DOM elements, the LAST DOM elements are removed;
      // basically, for each step, the data items "walks" leftward (each data 
      // item occupying the next DOM element to the left);
      // This data binding is very different from one that is done with a key 
      // function; in such a case, a data item stays "resident" in the DOM
      // element, and such DOM element (with data) would be moved left, until
      // the x position is to the left of the chart, where the item would be 
      // exited
      var updateSel = barG.selectAll(".bar")
          .data(data);

      // remove items
      updateSel.exit().remove();

      // append items
      updateSel.enter().append("rect")
          .attr("class", "bar")
          .attr("id", function() { 
            return "bar-" + barId++; 
          })
          .attr("shape-rendering", "crispEdges");

      // update items
      updateSel
          .attr("x", function(d) { return Math.round(x(d.time) - barWidth); })
          .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
          .attr("width", barWidth)
          .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
          .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color == undefined ? "black" : d.color; })
          //.style("stroke", "none")
          //.style("stroke-width", "1px")
          //.style("stroke-opacity", 0.5)
          .style("fill-opacity", 1);

      // also, bind data to nav chart
      // first remove current paths
      navG.selectAll("path").remove();

      // then append area path...
      navG.append('path')
          .attr('class', 'area')
          .attr('d', navArea(data));

      // ...and line path
      navG.append('path')
          .attr('class', 'line')
          .attr('d', navLine(data)); 

    } // end refreshChart function


    // function to keep the chart "moving" through time (right to left) 
         window.intvl = setInterval(function() {

      // get current viewport extent
      // var extent = viewport.empty() ? xNav.domain() : viewport.extent();
      var extent = (sel === null) ? xNav.domain() : viewport.extent();
      window.extent = extent;
      var interval = extent[1].getTime() - extent[0].getTime();
      var offset = extent[0].getTime() - xNav.domain()[0].getTime();

      // compute new nav extents
      endTime = new Date();
      startTime = new Date(endTime.getTime() - maxSeconds * 1000);

      // compute new viewport extents 
      startTimeViewport = new Date(startTime.getTime() + offset);
      endTimeViewport = new Date(startTimeViewport.getTime() + interval);
      viewport.extent([startTimeViewport, endTimeViewport])

      // update scales
      x.domain([startTimeViewport, endTimeViewport]);
      xNav.domain([startTime, endTime]);

      // update axis
      xAxis.scale(x)(xAxisG);
      xAxisNav.scale(xNav)(xAxisGNav);

      // refresh svg
      refresh();

    }, 200)

    // end setInterval function

    return chart;

  } // end chart function


  // chart getter/setters

  // array of inital data
  chart.initialData = function(_) {
    if (arguments.length == 0) return initialData;
    initialData = _;
    return chart;
  }

  // new data item (this most recent item will appear 
  // on the right side of the chart, and begin moving left)
  chart.datum = function(_) {
    if (arguments.length == 0) return datum;
    datum = _;
    data.push(datum);
    return chart;
  }

  // svg width
  chart.width = function(_) {
    if (arguments.length == 0) return svgWidth;
    svgWidth = _;
    return chart;
  }

  // svg height
  chart.height = function(_) {
    if (arguments.length == 0) return svgHeight;
    svgHeight = _;
    return chart;
  }

  // svg border
  chart.border = function(_) {
    if (arguments.length == 0) return border;
    border = _;
    return chart;       
  }

  // chart title
  chart.title = function(_) {
    if (arguments.length == 0) return chartTitle;
    chartTitle = _;
    return chart;   
  }

  // x axis title
  chart.xTitle = function(_) {
    if (arguments.length == 0) return xTitle;
    xTitle = _;
    return chart;       
  }

  // y axis title
  chart.yTitle = function(_) {
    if (arguments.length == 0) return yTitle;
    yTitle = _;
    return chart;       
  }

  // bar width
  chart.barWidth = function(_) {
    if (arguments.length == 0) return barWidth;
    barWidth = _;
    return chart;       
  }

  // version
  chart.version = version;

  return chart;

} // end realTimeChart function
```

https://jsfiddle.net/drhhw8c2/

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: The brush changed significantly with `d3.js v4`.  Right off the bat, in your fiddle, the brush isn't even being set up correctly (your call to extent is wrong -- should be `.extent([ [0,0], [widthNav,heightNav] ])`.  I suggest you port this one piece at a time instead of attempting a line by line.  You should also [read this](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#brushes-d3-brush).  For example, your `extent` calls aren't working because (from the docs) `rushes no longer store the active brush selection (i.e., the highlighted region; the brush’s position) internally.`...

Comment: Thank you for your comment, what calls to extent are wrong? I'm having difficulty understanding how the differences in the changes document translate to differences in code. If you could provide an updated jsfiddle that would be appreciated, thanks again.

Comment: In v3 `.extent` on a brush held the current selection of the brush.  This is not the case in v4 (that's why I highlighted that section of the documentation above).  Unfortunately, updating your fiddle is non-trivial and would take many hours.  You'll be hard-pressed to find someone on StackOverflow willing to wade through that wall of code.

Answer (score 2):

Finally got a working solution based on Mark's advice: https://jsfiddle.net/drhhw8c2/1/

```
function realTimeChart() {

  var version = "0.1.0",
      datum, initialData, data,
      maxSeconds = 300, pixelsPerSecond = 10,
      svgWidth = 700, svgHeight = 300,
      margin = { top: 20, bottom: 20, left: 50, right: 30, topNav: 10, bottomNav: 20 },
      dimension = { chartTitle: 20, xAxis: 20, yAxis: 20, xTitle: 20, yTitle: 20, navChart: 70 },
      barWidth = 3,
      maxY = 100, minY = 0,
      chartTitle, yTitle, xTitle,
      drawXAxis = true, drawYAxis = true, drawNavChart = true,
      border,
      selection,
      barId = 0;

  // create the chart
  var chart = function(s) {
    selection = s;
    if (selection == undefined) {
      console.error("selection is undefined");
      return;
    };

    // process titles
    chartTitle = chartTitle || "";
    xTitle = xTitle || "";
    yTitle = yTitle || "";

    // compute component dimensions
    var chartTitleDim = chartTitle == "" ? 0 : dimension.chartTitle;
    var xTitleDim = xTitle == "" ? 0 : dimension.xTitle;
    var yTitleDim = yTitle == "" ? 0 : dimension.yTitle;
    var xAxisDim = !drawXAxis ? 0 : dimension.xAxis;
    var yAxisDim = !drawYAxis ? 0 : dimension.yAxis;
    var navChartDim = !drawNavChart ? 0 : dimension.navChart;

    // compute chart dimension and offset
    var marginTop = margin.top + chartTitleDim;
    var height = svgHeight - marginTop - margin.bottom - chartTitleDim - xTitleDim - xAxisDim - navChartDim + 30;
    var heightNav = navChartDim - margin.topNav - margin.bottomNav;
    var marginTopNav = svgHeight - margin.bottom - heightNav - margin.topNav;
    var width = svgWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
    var widthNav = width;

    // append the svg
    var svg = selection.append("svg")
        .attr("width", svgWidth)
        .attr("height", svgHeight)
        .style("border", function(d) { 
          if (border) return "1px solid lightgray"; 
          else return null;
        });

    // create main group and translate
    var main = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate (" + margin.left + "," + marginTop + ")");

    // define clip-path
    main.append("defs").append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", "myClip")
      .append("rect")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    // create chart background
    main.append("rect")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .style("fill", "#f5f5f5");

    // note that two groups are created here, the latter assigned to barG;
    // the former will contain a clip path to constrain objects to the chart area; 
    // no equivalent clip path is created for the nav chart as the data itself
    // is clipped to the full time domain
    var barG = main.append("g")
        .attr("class", "barGroup")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0, 0)")
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#myClip")
      .append("g");

    // add group for x axis
    var xAxisG = main.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");

    // add group for y axis
    var yAxisG = main.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis");

    // in x axis group, add x axis title
    xAxisG.append("text")
        .attr("class", "title")
        .attr("x", width / 2)
        .attr("y", 25)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .text(function(d) { 
          var text = xTitle == undefined ? "" : xTitle;
          return text; 
        });

    // in y axis group, add y axis title
    yAxisG.append("text")
        .attr("class", "title")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("x", - height / 2)
        .attr("y", -35)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .text(function(d) { 
          var text = yTitle == undefined ? "" : yTitle;
          return text; 
        });

    // in main group, add chart title
    main.append("text")
        .attr("class", "chartTitle")
        .attr("x", width / 2)
        .attr("y", -20)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .text(function(d) { 
          var text = chartTitle == undefined ? "" : chartTitle;
          return text; 
        });

    // define main chart scales
    var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([minY, maxY]).range([height, 0]);

    // define main chart axis
    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);
    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

    // add nav chart
    var nav = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate (" + margin.left + "," + marginTopNav + ")");

    // add nav background
    nav.append("rect")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", heightNav)
        .style("fill", "#F5F5F5")
        .style("shape-rendering", "crispEdges")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0, 0)");

    // add group to hold line and area paths
    var navG = nav.append("g")
        .attr("class", "nav");

    // add group to hold nav x axis
    var xAxisGNav = nav.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + heightNav + ")");

    // define nav scales
    var xNav = d3.scaleTime().range([0, widthNav]);
    var yNav = d3.scaleLinear().domain([minY, maxY]).range([heightNav, 0]);

    // define nav axis
    var xAxisNav = d3.axisBottom(xNav);

    // define function that will draw the nav area chart
    var navArea = d3.area()
        .x(function (d) { return xNav(d.time); })
        .y1(function (d) { return yNav(d.value); })
        .y0(heightNav);

    // define function that will draw the nav line chart
    var navLine = d3.line()
        .x(function (d) { return xNav(d.time); })
        .y(function (d) { return yNav(d.value); });

    // compute initial time domains...
    var ts = new Date().getTime();

    // first, the full time domain
    var endTime = new Date(ts);
    var startTime = new Date(endTime.getTime() - maxSeconds * 1000);
    var interval = endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime();

    // then the viewport time domain (what's visible in the main chart 
    // and the viewport in the nav chart)
    var endTimeViewport = new Date(ts);
    var startTimeViewport = new Date(endTime.getTime() - width / pixelsPerSecond * 1000);
    var intervalViewport = endTimeViewport.getTime() - startTimeViewport.getTime();
    var offsetViewport = startTimeViewport.getTime() - startTime.getTime();

    // set the scale domains for main and nav charts
    x.domain([startTimeViewport, endTimeViewport]);
    xNav.domain([startTime, endTime]); 

    // update axis with modified scale
    xAxis.scale(x)(xAxisG);
    yAxis.scale(y)(yAxisG);
    xAxisNav.scale(xNav)(xAxisGNav);

    // create brush (moveable, changable rectangle that determines 
    // the time domain of main chart)
    var sel;
    var viewport = d3.brushX()
        // .x(xNav)
        // .extent([startTimeViewport, endTimeViewport])
        .extent([ [0,0], [widthNav,heightNav] ])
        .on("brush end", function () {
          // get the current time extent of viewport
          var extent = d3.event.selection || xNav.range();
          // var extent = d3.event.selection || x.range();

          // console.log(extent);
          startTimeViewport = xNav.invert(extent[0]);
          endTimeViewport = xNav.invert(extent[1]);

          console.log(startTimeViewport.getMinutes() + ':' + startTimeViewport.getSeconds() + ' - ' + endTimeViewport.getMinutes() + ':' + endTimeViewport.getSeconds());
          intervalViewport = endTimeViewport.getTime() - startTimeViewport.getTime();
          offsetViewport = startTimeViewport.getTime() - startTime.getTime();

          // handle invisible viewport
          if (intervalViewport == 0) {
            intervalViewport = maxSeconds * 1000;
            offsetViewport = 0;
          }

          // update the x domain of the main chart
          x.domain((extent === null) ? xNav.domain() : extent);

          // update the x axis of the main chart
          xAxis.scale(x)(xAxisG);/**/

          sel = d3.event.selection || xNav.range();
          x.domain(sel.map(xNav.invert, xNav));




          // update display
          refresh();
        });

      window.viewport = viewport;

    // create group and assign to brush
    var viewportG = nav.append("g")
        .attr("class", "viewport")
        .call(viewport)
        .selectAll("rect")
        .attr("height", heightNav);


    // initial invocation
    data = initialData || [];

    // update display
    refresh();


    // function to refresh the viz upon changes of the time domain 
    // (which happens constantly), or after arrival of new data,
    // or at init
    function refresh() {



      // process data to remove too late or too early data items 
      // (the latter could occur if the chart is stopped, while data
      // is being pumped in)
      data = data.filter(function(d) {
        if (d.time.getTime() > startTime.getTime() &&
            d.time.getTime() < endTime.getTime()) 
          return true;
      })


      // here we bind the new data to the main chart
      // note: no key function is used here; therefore the data binding is
      // by index, which effectivly means that available DOM elements
      // are associated with each item in the available data array, from 
      // first to last index; if the new data array contains fewer elements
      // than the existing DOM elements, the LAST DOM elements are removed;
      // basically, for each step, the data items "walks" leftward (each data 
      // item occupying the next DOM element to the left);
      // This data binding is very different from one that is done with a key 
      // function; in such a case, a data item stays "resident" in the DOM
      // element, and such DOM element (with data) would be moved left, until
      // the x position is to the left of the chart, where the item would be 
      // exited
      var updateSel = barG.selectAll(".bar")
          .data(data);

      // remove items
      updateSel.exit().remove();

      // append items
      updateSel.enter().append("rect")
          .attr("class", "bar")
          .attr("id", function() { 
            return "bar-" + barId++; 
          })
          .attr("shape-rendering", "crispEdges");
      // update items
      updateSel
          .attr("x", function(d) { 
            // console.log(x(d.time));
            var val = Math.round(x(d.time) - barWidth);
            if(val !== val) {
              val = 0;
            }
            return val; })

          .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
          .attr("width", barWidth)
          .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
          .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color == undefined ? "black" : d.color; })
          //.style("stroke", "none")
          //.style("stroke-width", "1px")
          //.style("stroke-opacity", 0.5)
          .style("fill-opacity", 1);

      // also, bind data to nav chart
      // first remove current paths
      navG.selectAll("path").remove();

      // then append area path...
      navG.append('path')
          .attr('class', 'area')
          .attr('d', navArea(data));

      // ...and line path
      navG.append('path')
          .attr('class', 'line')
          .attr('d', navLine(data)); 

    } // end refreshChart function


    // function to keep the chart "moving" through time (right to left) 
         window.intvl = setInterval(function() {

      // get current viewport extent
      // var extent = viewport.empty() ? xNav.domain() : viewport.extent();
      // var extent = (sel === null) ? xNav.domain() : viewport.extent()();
      var extent = xNav.domain();
      window.extent = extent;
           var interval = extent[1] - extent[0];
      var offset = extent[0] - xNav.domain()[0];
      // var interval = extent[1].getTime() - extent[0].getTime();
      // var offset = extent[0].getTime() - xNav.domain()[0].getTime();
      // compute new nav extents
      endTime = new Date();
      startTime = new Date(endTime.getTime() - maxSeconds * 1000);

      // compute new viewport extents 
      startTimeViewport = new Date(startTime.getTime() + offset);
      endTimeViewport = new Date(startTimeViewport.getTime() + interval);
      viewport.extent([startTimeViewport, endTimeViewport])

      // update scales

      x.domain([startTimeViewport, endTimeViewport]);
      if(sel) {
        x.domain(sel.map(xNav.invert, xNav));
      }
      xNav.domain([startTime, endTime]);

      // update axis
      xAxis.scale(x)(xAxisG);
      xAxisNav.scale(xNav)(xAxisGNav);


      // refresh svg
      refresh();

    }, 200)

    // end setInterval function

    return chart;

  } // end chart function


  // chart getter/setters

  // array of inital data
  chart.initialData = function(_) {
    if (arguments.length == 0) return initialData;
    initialData = _;
    return chart;
  }

  // new data item (this most recent item will appear 
  // on the right side of the chart, and begin moving left)
  chart.datum = function(_) {
    if (arguments.length == 0) return datum;
    datum = _;
    data.push(datum);
    return chart;
  }

  // svg width
  chart.width = function(_) {
    if (arguments.length == 0) return svgWidth;
    svgWidth = _;
    return chart;
  }

  // svg height
  chart.height = function(_) {
    if (arguments.length == 0) return svgHeight;
    svgHeight = _;
    return chart;
  }

  // svg border
  chart.border = function(_) {
    if (arguments.length == 0) return border;
    border = _;
    return chart;       
  }

  // chart title
  chart.title = function(_) {
    if (arguments.length == 0) return chartTitle;
    chartTitle = _;
    return chart;   
  }

  // x axis title
  chart.xTitle = function(_) {
    if (arguments.length == 0) return xTitle;
    xTitle = _;
    return chart;       
  }

  // y axis title
  chart.yTitle = function(_) {
    if (arguments.length == 0) return yTitle;
    yTitle = _;
    return chart;       
  }

  // bar width
  chart.barWidth = function(_) {
    if (arguments.length == 0) return barWidth;
    barWidth = _;
    return chart;       
  }

  // version
  chart.version = version;

  return chart;

} // end realTimeChart function


'use strict';

// mean and deviation for time interval
var meanMs = 1000, // milliseconds
    dev = 150;

// define time scale
var timeScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([300, 1700])
    .range([300, 1700])
    .clamp(true);

// define value scale
var valueScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 1])
    .range([30, 95]);

// generate initial data
var normal = d3.randomNormal(1000, 150);
var currMs = new Date().getTime() - 300000 - 4000;
var data = d3.range(300).map(function(d, i, arr) {
  var value = valueScale(Math.random()); // random data
  //var value = Math.round((d % 60) / 60 * 95); // ramp data
  var interval = Math.round(timeScale(normal()));
  currMs += interval;
  var time = new Date(currMs);
  var obj = { interval: interval, value: value, time: time, ts: currMs }
  return obj;
})

// create the real time chart
var chart = realTimeChart()
    .title("Chart Title")
    .yTitle("Y Scale")
    .xTitle("X Scale")
    .border(true)
    .width(600)
    .height(290)
    .barWidth(1)
    .initialData(data);

console.log("Version: ", chart.version);
console.dir("Dir++");
console.trace();
console.warn("warn")

// invoke the chart
var chartDiv = d3.select("#viewDiv").append("div")
    .attr("id", "chartDiv")
    .call(chart);

// alternative invocation
//chart(chartDiv); 


// drive data into the chart roughly every second
// in a normal use case, real time data would arrive through the network or some other mechanism
var d = 0;
function dataGenerator() {

  var timeout = Math.round(timeScale(normal()));

  setTimeout(function() {

    // create new data item
    var now = new Date();
    var obj = {
      value: valueScale(Math.random()), // random data
      //value: Math.round((d++ % 60) / 60 * 95), // ramp data
      time: now,
      color: "red",
      ts: now.getTime(),
      interval: timeout
    };

    // send the datum to the chart
    chart.datum(obj);

    // do forever
    dataGenerator();

  }, timeout);
}

// start the data generator
dataGenerator();
```